# How to return nothing and close connection in asp .net for GET request

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, get

I have a simple asp .net web form. I want to let the web form return nothing and close connection immediately when the particular value at Query String is not right. How do I do that?

I mean stop processing the request without returning anything at all and close the connection. Any idea?

Comment: I'am not completely sure, but I think you can use Response.Clear() and Response.End() http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525405(v=VS.90).aspx

Comment: What do you mean by Close the connection ?

Comment: Do you want to exit from the page, if query string is invalid ?

Comment: typical html connection. Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you want to close the page ?

Comment: @Muhammad Akhtar, I mean the asp net page stop process the GET request if query string is invalid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although [Response.End()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.end%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) has been mentioned, it raises exceptions (ThreadAbortException). If you're expecting to do this often, then the performance of your site might decrease because of this. Instead, you could use [HttpApplication.CompleteRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.completerequest.aspx) which ends the request, but not throw an exception.

Comment: you mean call this Response.ClearContent() first then HttpApplication.CompleteRequest ?

Comment: @Dee Jay: Yes, you could do that.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
Response.ClearContent();
Response.End();
```

You can call this from the master page, the page or a user control.

You can get the response object otherwise using `HttpContext.Current.Response`